# Scroll to a div contained in a overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this:

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow:auto">
   ...
   <div id="test">Hello</div>
   ...
</div>
```

My question is: how to scroll parent div to have test div as first line of parent ?

Comment: @Dario: BTW...don't forget to mark the answer you went with as the solution for the next person who comes across your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a plugin, see [`element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollIntoView):

```
$("#test").get(0).scrollIntoView();

// Plain ol' JS:
document.getElementById("test").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I'd add a link to MSDN documentation too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536730%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: great! that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: Thanks, I usually add a link to either MDC or MSDN.  I only add both if there are differences between implementations. In this case, there are no differences so one link should be enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or are able to do so), take a look at the [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.

From documentation

> With this plugin, you will easily scroll overflowed elements, and the screen itself.
>   It gives you access to many different options to customize and various ways to specify where to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

The easiest way is to use this plugin.

Comment: anything without using a plugin?